# Shutdown error codes on Macbook

Tags: macos, error, shutdown

What does shutdown error code -59 on Macbook air mean? I can't find this specific code anywhere online

Answer (score 0):

From the [Krypted](https://krypted.com/lists/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/) site:

`fsRnErr = -59, /*file system internal error:during rename the old was deleted, restored.*/`

If you could give us more of a description of when this happened, (once? all the time?) and what version of macOS is running. Is this causing a problem? If so, please be more specific.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! So this happens quite frequently, my MacBook reboots when I close the lid. It doesn’t happen every time but it can happen multiple times a day. My MacBook is currently running the latest MacOS Ventura.

Comment: Did it start happening _after_ you updated to Ventura?

Comment: It was doing this before I updated to Ventura. I thought the update might fix it but it didn't.

Comment: Create a temporary new user (standard or admin, it doesn't matter) and see if this occurs when logged in as this user.

Comment: I’ll try this and get back you- thank you!

Comment: Hi, so the issue still occurs on the temporary new user I created